# for f(x,y,z) find point on surface nearest to origin

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

$f(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2-z^2$, $S=\{(x,y,z): f(x,y,z)=1\}$ find point on S nearest to origin.

I thought I would use Lagrange multipliers to solve this problem, but when I use $f(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2-z^2$ and $g(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2-z^2-1$, along with,
$$g(x,y,z)=0$$
$$f_x=\lambda g_x$$

$$f_y=\lambda g_y$$

$$f_z=\lambda g_z$$

I am getting not so good answers.  How to solve this type of problem

Answer (score 2):

The distance from $(x,y,z)$ to the origin is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

We therefore want to minimize $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, or equivalently $x^2+y^2+z^2$, subject to the condition $x^2+2y^2-z^2-1=0$. So $x^2+y^2+z^2$  should be your $f$. Now the usual process should work well.

Comment: Hi @AndreNicolas, what if we just tweaked this problem a bit and want to find the point nearest to the origin -- but now the constraint is not one plane but rather the intersection of two planes?  Would the approach, using Lagrange Multipliers, be significantly different?  I am working on a similar problem, and have used all of my equations and two constraints, but currently do not see a way to proceed.  Thanks,

Comment: It you ask the question it will be quickly answered, but not by me (it is late). Lagrange multipliers, two constraints, will work. But it is really a linear algebra problem. If you want to set it up as a calculus problem, find parametric equations of the line of intersection of the two planes. The parametric equations will involve a single parameter $t$, and you will be minimizing a quadratic in  $t$.

Comment: Hi @andrenicolas ok I will ask the question now, specifically for a linear algebraic approach to solve the problem.  Currently, I have used both plane equation constraints already and am stuck with $2(x^2+y^2+z^2) = \lambda_1(-a_0) + \lambda_2(-b_0)$.

Comment: Do you see an obvious maneuver from here?  Thanks so much, @andrenicolas

Comment: Nothing obvious, but I do not know full details of the problem. If you have already used Lagrange multipliers to minimize distance, then the equations should involve the partials with respect to $x,y,z$ so the first equation should have shape $2x=\dots$.

Comment: Hi @andrenicolas, I posted the problem and my work on MSE last night - it is my most recent question.  If you have some time, do you want to take a quick look at it? :-) the answers I received were unfortunately not helpful to me.  I also reviewed several, different two-constraint problems on MSE but this also has not led to more insight with my own problem.  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @andrenicolas, I have found one critical point, using linear algebra, but the point (x,y,z) is in a pretty nasty form.  This must be the point closest to the origin but is there some way I could justify it?  The point is expressed in terms of dot products and vector norms ... so it's a bit tricky.  Thanks,

Comment: I will try to get to it. It is a bit annoying to have letters rather than numbers.

Comment: Ok got it - thanks so much @andrenicolas :-)